# Create HTML Table in C# with foreach loop

Tags: c#, html-table

I want to create an HTML table with my c# program.

I've tried this:

```
internal string CreateMailBody(mailObj dataObj)
  {
      string body = string.Empty;
      body +=
          "Dear all, there is my new table:" +
          "TableNo: " + dataObj.Obj.Table.TableNumber+ "<br /> <br />";
      body += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Line No</th><th>Table</th><th>Description</th><th>Count</th><th>Met</th><th>something</th></tr>";
      foreach (var item in dataObj.Table.TableLineCollection)
      {
          body += "<tr><td>" + item.LineNumber +"</td>";
          body += "<tr><td>" + item.Table+"</td>";
          body += "<tr><td>" + item.Description+"</td></tr>";
      }
      return body;
  }
```

Will it give a better solution for this ?

Comment: Will what give a better solution?

Comment: To create the HTML table...i don't know if it is better to use a stringbuilder or so

Comment: In what way is this code not working?  Where does it fail?  It's not clear what you're asking or what the problem is.

Comment: You could do with a closing tag `</table>` after the loop

Comment: I only want to know if I can solve it "better"

Comment: @invidicult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126137/generate-html-table-from-list-of-generic-class-with-specified-properties

Comment: you're using a lot of string concatenation.  A StringBuilder would be better at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may mix StringBuilder using the method AppendFormat and string literals (@ in from of a string, so you can write multiple lines).

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
body.AppendFormat (
    @"Dear all, there is my new table:
    TableNo: {0} <br /> <br />
    <table border='1'><tr><th>Line No</th><th>Table</th><th>Description</th><th>Count</th><th>Met</th><th>something</th></tr>"
    , dataObj.Obj.Table.TableNumber);
foreach (var item in dataObj.Table.TableLineCollection)
{
    body.AppendFormat(
    @"<tr><td> {0}</td>
    <tr><td> {1}</td>
    <tr><td> {2}</td></tr>",
    item.LineNumber, item.Table, item.Description);
}
```